# The 2 skeleton of a 3 manifold is the 2 skeleton of a $K(\pi, 1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Recall that a topological space $M$ is called **aspherical** if is path connected and the homotopy groups $\pi_n(M) $ vanish for $n\geq 2$.

A (smooth) 3-manifold $M$ is an homology sphere if $H_*(M,\mathbb{Z})\simeq H_*(\mathbb{S}^3,\mathbb{Z})$.

> Is true that if a closed 3-manifold is an homology sphere then its 2-skeleton is aspherical? How can we see this?

I was reading a paper that at a certain point says assumes that the 2-skeleton is a $K(\pi,1)$ but I can't see how to use the assumption on the homology groups of $M$ to prove asphericity.

Comment: I think you want to assume $M\not\cong\Bbb S^3$.

Comment: @M.Winter Thank you, I've changed the question.

Comment: Can you tell us which paper you are reading?

Comment: This implies the group homology of the fundamental group vanishes above 1. Is this known to happen?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese see the last line on page 3 of https://www.math.ksu.edu/~dav/sf.pdf apparently he doesn't even need $M$ to be a $\mathbb{Z }H \mathbb{S}^3$. Notice that it's only the 2 skeleton we are caring about

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what was being claimed.

> Since the $2$-skeleton on $M$ is the $2$-skeleton of a $K(\pi_1(M), 1)$ ...

It is not claimed that the $2$-skeleton of $M$ is a $K(\pi_1(M), 1)$. Rather, there is a $K(\pi_1(M), 1)$ which has the same $2$-skeleton as $M$.

This has nothing to do with homology spheres or even manifolds. If $X$ is a two-dimensional CW complex, then we can add cells in dimensions at least three to obtain a $K(\pi_1(X), 1)$. The two-skeleton of this $K(\pi_1(X), 1)$ is $X$ itself (because we only added cells of higher dimension).